# Estimation of unobserved variable

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation, estimation, kalman-filter, stochastic-filtering

I am applying Kalman Filter to estimate the states of a particle moving along x direction. The states of the particle at any discrete time $t = k$ are $\left[x_k \hspace{3pt} \dot{x}_k \hspace{3pt} \ddot{x}_k\right]^T$. However I can only observe $x_k$ and $\dot{x}_k$ and there is no observation for $\ddot{x}_k$. We can also see that $x$ and $\dot{x}_k$ have no projection along $\ddot{x}_k$. So, for any given measurement, there is no direct information about $\ddot{x}_k$. My aim is to find $\ddot{x}_k$ as accurately as possible. There are two possible ways:

1. Kalman Filter( KF): Since the observed measurements do not have any projection along the $\ddot{x}_k$,  the estimate of $\ddot{x}_k$ will be very noisy and may be way off from the true value of $\ddot{x}_k$.
2. Use Kalman Filter as in step 1 to do the estimation for all parameters, but in addition to that, use first order low pass filter(LPF) to get a more accurate and less noisy estimate of $\ddot{x}_k$  i.e.
   $\ddot{x}_k = \alpha \ddot{x}_{k-1} + \left(1-\alpha\right)\frac{\dot{x}_{k} - \dot{x}_{k-1}}{\Delta t}$

However, the value of $\ddot{x}_k$, so obtained, will not be used in
the propagation or update step of KF and hence cannot influence the
$x_k$ and $\dot{x}_k$ estimate. So, there will be inconsistency
among the values $x_k$, $\dot{x}_k$ and the LPF based $\ddot{x}_k$.
This may create problems.

Now, there is another way to get a more accurate estimate of $x$, $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$. But I am not sure about its validity. It goes like this:

3. Basically, in addition to the observed states $x_k$ and $\dot{x}_k$ for Kalman Filter method, we can introduce a pseudo-observation of $\ddot{x}_k = \frac{\dot{x}_{k} - \dot{x}_{k-1}}{\Delta t}$, where $\Delta t$ is the time difference between $t = k$ and $t = k-1$. While practically, this value is $\ddot{x}_{k-1}$, this will maintain consistency among all the states.

I also understand that by introducing this pseudo-observation, I am
forcing a mathematical relationship among acceleration, velocity and time, which
may not exist for the given system and this is against the basic
concept of filtering. So, does anyone think that this method of
introducing the pseudo-observation is legit?

Kalman filter equations:

Propagation: \begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}_{k+1} \\
\hat{\dot{x}}_{k+1} \\
\hat{\ddot{x}}_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \Delta t & \frac{\Delta t^2}{2} \\
0 & 1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k} \\
\dot{x}_{k} \\
\ddot{x}_{k}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\eta \frac{\Delta t^3}{6} \\
\eta \frac{\Delta t^2}{2} \\
\eta \Delta t
\end{bmatrix}, \hspace{10pt} \eta \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, Q\right)
\end{equation*}

Update:
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1\\
z_2
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}_{k+1} \\
\hat{\dot{x}}_{k+1} \\
\hat{\ddot{x}}_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\nu_1 \\
\nu_2
\end{bmatrix}\hspace{10pt}, \nu_i \sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, R_i\right)
\end{equation*}

Comment: Have you tried to use method 1, the normal Kalman filter, with appropriately chosen noise covariance matrices?

Comment: Yes. I have tried the first method and the estimated value of $\ddot{x}$ was about 1/10 of the true value. I also tried different reasonable values for covariance matrices. There was not much difference in the result.

Comment: Are the signals coming from a simulation (so you know the truth state values) or from measurements from an actual system? Also did you verify that your model used for the Kalman filter is correct?

Comment: I have true values collected using GPS and IMU installed on the target(i.e. particle in this case) . I have added KF equations in the description

Comment: In that case, it is very likely that your model is not completely correct. But do you really need to have a good estimate of $\ddot{x}_k$? Namely, $\ddot{x}_k$ would be the most sensitive to model inaccuracies and $x_k$ the least. So if you are more interested in $x_k$ then maybe this model might be good enough. And how do you know that the predicted $\ddot{x}$ is off by that much from the true $\ddot{x}$? Are you using the accelerometer for this, if so did you compensate for gravity? Could you maybe also add plots?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload the plots due to proprietary issues. However I have verified that the ground truth values for $\ddot{x}_k$ are correct, as I get same values when I use estimated velocity values to compute $\frac{\dot{x}_k-\dot{x}_{k-1}}{\Delta t}$. I need acceleration estimate as it is a leader-follower system where the follower needs to know the exact states(position, velocity, acceleration of the leader to avoid collision.

Comment: I still suspect it is due to using an incorrect model. To verify this you could generate your own data using the same model as used for the Kalman filter, in which case the normal Kalman filter should work. Have you also tried to perform any system identification on your gathered data?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I did not perform any system identification on the collected data. But I know that the system’s acceleration is non zero for most part. 
However my question is how can we estimate acceleration accurately when the measurement data has no information about it?

Comment: The measured data does contain indirect information about the acceleration, but because of measurement noise it is harder to extract. But by fitting a model and then utilizing it in the Kalman filter should enable you the extract a better estimation of the acceleration.